# Как работает функция int() в Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Задача «Следующее и предыдущее»
>   Условие
>   Напишите программу, которая считывает целое число и выводит текст, аналогичный приведенному в примере (пробелы важны!).

Записываю:

```
num = int(input())
print = str('The next number for the number ' + num + 'is ' + num + 1)
print = str('The previous number for the number ' + num + 'is ' + num - 1)
```

И выдаёт такую ошибку в визуализаторе на сайте:

> TypeError на строке 2: Can't convert int to str implicitely

Когда срабатывает функция *int* и почему она не переводится в *str*?

Comment: Не переводится, потому что вы переводите не int в str, а ожидаете неявно преобразования типа, складывая str + int + str +int + int, а уж потом этот результат (и какой тип вы у него предполагаете?) приводите к строке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу текста ошибки:

> TypeError на строке 2: Can't convert int to str implicitely

Здесь `int` и `str` - не функции, а типы, соответственно целое и строка. Буквально "нельзя конвертировать целое в строку неявно". Т.е. нужно переводить *явно* (об этом дальше).

*(Ниже ответ на несуществущий уже комментарий, который, тем не менее, существенен в контексте вопроса)*

> А почему str не приводит числа и переменные к строке после обработки внутри скобок?

Все что в скобках внутри во второй и третьей строке - это не отдельные аргументы функции `str`, это выражение (которое должно будет выполнится то того, как его результат попадет в функцию `str`), где вы пытаетесь каким-то образом сложить целые числа и строки. В Python такой номер не прокатит. Если нужно объединить все в одну строку, сначала приведите числа (или другие объекты) к строкам, а потом уже объединяйте все как строки.

И не нужно присваивать функции `print` полученную строку, функцию `print` нужно вызывать, а не присваивать ей что-то. Если вам по условию нужно что-то вывести, то функцию `print` нужно вызвать, а не перезаписать ее чем-то.

Исправленный код:

```
num = int(input())
print('The next number for the number ' + str(num) + 'is ' + str(num + 1))
print('The previous number for the number ' + str(num) + 'is ' + str(num - 1))
```

Или можно просто перечислить все части как аргументы функции `print` через запятую, тогда явное приведение к строке не нужно будет (`print` каждый аргумент приведет к строке сам), и пробелы между частями выводимого текста `print` тоже расставит сам:

```
num = int(input())
print('The next number for the number', num, 'is', num + 1)
print('The previous number for the number', num, 'is', num - 1)
```

Comment: Да это я дурак, случайно написал. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input())
num1 = num + 1
num2 = num - 1
print('The next number for the number ' + str(num) + ' is ' + str(num1))
print('The previous number for the number ' + str(num) + ' is ' + str(num2))
```

Comment: Я думаю что подобные строки через форматирование лучше будут смотреться (мб стоит вам добавить вариант с ними ниже), вот пример: `print('The next number for the number {} is {}'.format(num, num1))` или вариант через f-строки: `print(f'The next number for the number {num} is {num1}')` И используйте операторы `-=` и `+=`: `num1 += 1` и `num2 -= 1`